# Pip mods don't seem to install

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, pip

So I just downloaded Python 3.6.1 now using pip I tried to download matplotlib.

```
pip install --user matplotlib
```

After it's "successful" download I open Python EDGE, import matplotlib only to receive this message.

> NameError: name 'matplotlib' is not defined

Could previously using pip on Python 3.5 be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install with exactly your version of Python:

```
python3.6 -m pip install --user matplotlib
```

or

```
C:\Python36\python.exe -m pip install --user matplotlib
```

The probmle is that `pip` could use a different version of Python.

Comment: I have tried this and I am hit with an error " 'python3.6.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command ".

Comment: On Unix the program is `python3.6`, on w32 `C:\Python36\python.exe`.  Neither `python3.6.1` nor `C:\Python361\python.exe`.

Comment: haha well I did figure it out on my own and it wasn't what you had said but ill give it to you.